# Auto focus and maxlength for type number

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a program that will skip to the next field after you enter the maximum allowed in the previous field.  The input maxlength attribute does not work for type="number".  Therefore, I have a javascript to make sure the maxlength is followed and only numerics are allowed.

```
<form action="myprogram.htm" method="post" name="myform">
<input type="number" size="5" maxlength="2" name="num1" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);" required>
<input type="number" size="5" maxlength="2" name="num2" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);" required>
<input type="number" size="5" maxlength="2" name="num3" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);" required>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("input").bind("input", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        if ( $this.val().length >= parseInt($this.attr("maxlength"),10) )
            $this.next("input").focus();
    },0);
});

function isNumberKey(evt){
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
    return !(charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57));
}
</script>
```

However, there are three problems with this that I can't seem to solve.

1. The maxlength works for the first two fields, num1 and num2.  But the third field can enter more than 2!  Not sure why this is happening.
2. If the 3 fields are already filled in e.g. 11, 22, 33.  If you move to the first field and overwrite it with the number 555, it will jump to the second field 22 and add the third "5" in the second field at the end of 22.  So you will end up with 225.  It seems the javascript is not able to enforce the maxlength in this case.
3. When you click on the first field "11" and try to use the up and down arrow to increase or decrease the number.  The focus/highlight jumps to the next field 22 while you are increasing or decreasing the first field.  I know the first field has reached the maxlength of two, but my cursor is still on the first field's arrow.

Is there any way to fix these?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```js
function enforceMaxLength(element) {
  if (element.value.length > 2) {
    element.value = element.value.slice(0, 2); // maxlength of 2
  }
}

$("input[type='number']").on('input', function(e) {
  enforceMaxLength(this);

  var nonArrowKeyTyped = $(this).data('nonArrowKeyTyped');
  if (nonArrowKeyTyped && this.value.length >= 2) {
    // shift focus if not using arrows and input full
    $(this).next("input").select();
    $(this).next("input").focus();
  }
  $(this).removeData('nonArrowKeyTyped');
});

$("input[type='number']").on('keydown', function(e) {
  var key = e.which || e.keyCode;

  if (!((key >= 48 && key <= 57) || // numeric keys
      (key >= 96 && key <= 105) || // numeric keypad
      key === 8 || // backspace
      key === 46 || // delete
      key === 9 || // tab
      key === 13 || // enter
      key === 37 || key === 39 || // left and right arrows
      key === 38 || key === 40 || // up and down arrows
      key <= 31 // control keys
    )) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  // check for non-arrow keys (excluding tab, shift, ctrl, etc.)
  if (![9, 16, 17, 18, 91, 38, 40].includes(key)) {
    $(this).data('nonArrowKeyTyped', true);
  }

  // allow shift tab
  if (e.shiftKey && key === 9) {
    $(this).prev("input").focus();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});

$("input[type='number']").on('click', function() {
  // set focus when arrows used
  $(this).focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="myprogram.htm" method="post" name="myform">
  <input type="number" size="5" name="num1" required>
  <input type="number" size="5" name="num2" required>
  <input type="number" size="5" name="num3" required>
</form>
```

This code snippet will:

1. Allow a maximum of 2 characters per input
2. Move the user's focus to the next input when the current active input is at it's character capacity
3. Will not move the user's focus when adjusting the value with the input's arrows
4. Will move the user's focus to an input when the arrows are used to adjust the input's value
5. Will allow the user to tab forward and backward between inputs
6. Will allow the user to delete the value in an input and enter a new value
7. Will select the value in next input when focus is moved to next input
8. Is tested and working on FireFox, Safari, and Chrome

Comment: Thank you.  There is an issue with it.  If I entered 11, 22, and 33.  I go back to 11 and tried to change it to 45, it will jump to the second number 22.  It won't let me change the field value except through the up and down arrow.

Comment: the second "issue" is when you entered 2 digits in the first field e.g. 11.  The focus does not jump to the second field until you enter a value while in the cursor is still in the first field.

Comment: Try entering 11, 22 and 33.  Move your cursor to 11 and try changing it to 45 (not using the up and down arrow) or delete it.  You won't be able to do it.

Comment: I need to be able to change the value using the keyboard or delete it.  I can't do it in FF.   I moved my cursor to 11.  As soon as I press delete, it jumps to the next field.  I think it is a FireFox thing.

Comment: The shift-tab seems to work now with the codes in Chrome and Edge.  But Firefox no luck.  It doesn't even jump to the next field when you enter 11.  It only jump when you start entering value 22. Still can't delete in FF.  So weird.  Pressing the shift key also act like a tab.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Who would have thought simple numeric fields has so many issues.  All the solutions given out there for auto skipping all have the same problems.  You just saved the world! :)

Comment: After entering 11, 22 and 33.  If I change 11 to 44, the cursor/focus will jump to field num2.  But the cursor will go to the end of num2 22.  Is there any way to jump/focus with select all (as if using tab) on num2, so that I can simply overwrite the value?

Comment: @Jack $(this).next("input").select(); below $(this).next("input").focus();

Comment: that didn't work.  It also messes up the shift tab function.

Comment: @Jack are you sure you put it in the right place? See updated code snippet in answer. I just tested it and it's working in firefox and chrome.

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  I put it in the wrong spot.  Thanks again!